# Serialize a string without changes in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Python's json.dumps() to convert an array to a string and then store it in a Django Model. I'm trying to figure out how I can get Django's REST framework to ignore this field and send it 'as is' without serializing it a second time.

For example, if the model looks like this(Both fields are CharFields):

> name = "E:\"
>
> path_with_ids= "[{"name": "E:\", "id": 525}]"

I want the REST framework to ignore 'path_with_ids' when serializing so the JSON output will look like this:

> { "name": "E:\", "path_with_ids": 
>       [     {"name": "E:\", "id": 525}  ] }

and not like this:

> {
>       "name": "E:\",
>       "path_with_ids": "[{\"name\": \"E:\\\", \"id\": 525}]" }

I've tried to make another serializer class that spits out the input it gets 'as is' without success:

**Serializers.py:**

```
class PathWithIds(serializers.CharField):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        return value.path_with_ids

class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

field_to_ignore = PathWithIds(source='path_with_ids')

  class Meta:
      model = Folder
      fields = ['id', 'field_to_ignore']
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a wasteful and sickening method of deserializing the array before serializing it again with the REST framework:

**Serializers.py:**

```
import json
class PathWithIds(serializers.CharField):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        x = json.loads(value)
        return x

class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    array_output = PathWithIds(source='field_to_ignore')

      class Meta:
          model = Folder
          fields = ['id', 'array_output']
```

**Output in the rest API:**

> {
>       "name": "E:\",
>       "array_output": [
>           {
>               "name": "E:\",
>               "id": 525
>           }
>       ] }

Comment: This is totally reasonable since you're converting a field to a native type. What you're hoping for bypasses the serialization process completely and would just be a blind append that could very easily fail.